# Yii dropdownlist using $form-> dropdownlist

Tags: php, yii

i want to create a form from 2 different models, 
1st is for countries, and the 2nd is for documents.
The problem is that i can't make a dropdown list, i get the errors all the time.

Here's the code, first my controller.php part

```
$model = new Country;
$model2 = new Product;

    $this->performAjaxValidation(array($model, $model2));
    if(isset($_POST['Country'],$_POST['Product']))
    {
        // populate input data to $model and $model2
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Country'];
        $model2->attributes=$_POST['Product'];

        // validate BOTH $model and $model2
        $valid=$model->validate();
        $valid=$model2->validate() && $valid;

        if($valid)
        {
            // use false parameter to disable validation
            $model->save(false);
            $model2->save(false);

            $this->redirect('index');
        }
    }
...
$countriesIssued = Country::model()->findAll(array('select'=>'code, name', 'order'=>'name'));
...
     $this->render('legalisation', array('model'=>$model, 'model2'=>$model2, 'documents'=>$documents, 'countriesIssued'=>$countriesIssued, 'countries'=>$countries, 'flag'=>$flag));
    }
```

In my view script I use this code

```
      <?php $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'user-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
)); ?>

<?php echo $form->errorSummary(array($model,$model2)); ?>

<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'countriesIssued',
        CHtml::listData($countriesIssued, 'code', 'name'));?>


<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

but i get this error :
**Property "Country.countriesIssued" is not defined.**

Ok it's not defined, i try to change it to 'countriesIssued', then i got another error saying **Invalid argument supplied for foreach()** .

If anybody can help me please. 
I know there is more solutions on net, i try it but not understand, Thanks.

Comment: your var `countriesissued` is not an array but its an object.Thats why you got invalid arguement error.instead use the solution below given by me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By definition, the first param of listData is an array; Your is a object;

```
    <?php 
echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'classification_levels_id', CHtml::listData(ClassificationLevels::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'name'),$classification_levels_options);
?>
```

Comment: can you please tell me what is classification_levels_id ? thanks

Comment: ok, i get it, 
<?php $countriesList = CHtml::listData($countriesIssued, 'code', 'name');?>
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'code',
CHtml::listData(country::model()->findAll(), 'code', 'name'), $countriesList);?>

Comment: Why use `$countriesList`. This is useless in this code,Instead echo like this. `$form->dropDownList($model, 'code', CHtml::listData(country::model()->findAll(), 'code', 'name'),array('empty'=>'Select Country')); `

Answer (score 2):

Make a list variable like this:

In your Model:

```
$countriesIssued = Country::model()->findAll(array('select'=>'code, name', 'order'=>'name'));
```

And in your view:

```
$list = CHtml::listData($countriesIssued, 'code', 'name'));

 echo CHtml::dropDownList('Your variable', Your $model, 
          $list,
          array('empty' => '(Select a category'));
```

Comment: Thank you very much it finally works, can you please tell me why to put this $countriesIssued into the model, and not in controller, thanks.

Comment: you can make it in your controller too...am just passing an easier way to do this.

Comment: this is ok in _form.php and what to do in view.php? How to echo the selected value ?

Answer (score 2):

dropDownList($model,'state',array('1' => 'Do 1', '2' => 'Do 2'),array('selected' => 'Choose')); ?>

Or Yii 2

field($model,'state')->dropDownList(
      array('1' => 'Do 1','0' => 'Do 2'),array('options' => array('0' => array('selected' => true))))
      ->label('State')
    ?>